# Array of Array of structs in c99

Tags: c, arrays, struct, c99

I am trying to implement hash maps in c. I am trying to go about this by creating a struct to hold the hash and key like this.

```
struct bucket{
char * key;
char * value;
};
```

Then i am create an array of these structs to hold all the hashs that are the same but with different keys. like so:

```
struct bucket * buckets;
buckets = malloc(numberOfBuckets);
```

Then where i am getting stuck is making an array to store these arrays in. I thought it was done like this:

```
struct bucket * arrayOfArrays;
arrayOfArrays = malloc(++numberOfKeys);
arrayOfArrays[0] = buckets;
```

which is giving me the error:

```
incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct bucket' from type 'struct bucket *'
```

Comment: You are probably allocating too little memory, just so you know. Unless your example is poorly written pseudo code.

Comment: Think about what you're doing.  If there are n keys, then you're allocating n bytes.  You need to allocate n `struct bucket`.  Hint:  You need to use `sizeof` to calculate the number of bytes.

Comment: @StoryTeller sorry forgot to include the 2nd malloc for arrayOfArrays

Comment: No, I'm talking about the first malloc, actually

Comment: That is absolutely not the error you're getting. Do not invent error messages. Copy-paste them verbatim.

Comment: The error message talks about `id`. There is nothing called `id` in the code you show.

Comment: btw this is not hash map should be implemented

Comment: @texasbruce so how would you suggest implementing it?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala not inventing errors just did not see the higher error in the console have updated it to the one that was above it now

Comment: @Sean it is not true. The error message in the original edit *was not* a verbatim copy of the actual error that you received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct bucket * arrayOfArrays;
arrayOfArrays[0] = buckets;
```

Change this to

```
struct bucket ** arrayOfArrays;
arrayOfArrays = malloc(sizeof(struct bucket *) * numberOfArrays);
arrayOfArrays[0] = buckets;
```

And it should work for you.

You also need to change the first allocation to get enough bytes:

```
struct bucket * buckets;
buckets = malloc(sizeof(struct bucket) * numberOfBuckets);
```